# Changing values in copied list changes more than the value

Tags: python, list, copy

I am creating a copy of a list, but when later change a value in the copied list, it changes more than that value.

```
def NewField(h,c):         
    r = []
    r2 = []
    r3 = []
    for i in range(c):
        r2 += ["0"]
    for i in range(c):
        r3 += ["-"]

    for i in range(h):
        r += [r2]
    r += [r3]
    for i in range(h):
        r += [r2]  
    return r


test_field = NewField(3,4)

def NewMan(f,p,c):
    f1 = f[:]
    f1[c[0]-1][c[1]-1] = p
    return f1
NewMan(test_field,"8",[1,2])
```

I've also tried deepcopy()

Comment: can you produce an example? Like what you provide as an input, what is your desired output & what the code is producing

Comment: The output is [['0', '8', '0', '0'],
 ['0', '8', '0', '0'],
 ['0', '8', '0', '0'],
 ['-', '-', '-', '-'],
 ['0', '8', '0', '0'],
 ['0', '8', '0', '0'],
 ['0', '8', '0', '0']] , while the desired is [['0', '8', '0', '0'],
 ['0', '0', '0', '0'],
 ['0', '0', '0', '0'],
 ['-', '-', '-', '-'],
 ['0', '0', '0', '0'],
 ['0', '0', '0', '0'],
 ['0', '0', '0', '0']]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the sublists `r2` are all copies of another. Try this:

```
def NewField(h,c):         
    r = []
    r2 = []
    r3 = []
    for i in range(c):
        r2 += ["0"]
    for i in range(c):
        r3 += ["-"]

    for i in range(h):
        r += [r2[:]] # added [:]
    r += [r3]
    for i in range(h):
        r += [r2[:]] # added [:]
    return r
```